# Why does Google keep hitting only one MP3 file?

Tags: seo, googlebot, page-views

I have a bunch of Mp3 files on my site, and all if them are in the sitemap to allow search engines that log mp3 files to know about them. For some reason, every day or two, Google keeps hitting the same file.

The weird part is, it's file index 11. Not the top, not the bottom, and always the same file. Does anybody have a clue on why that would be happening? In contrast, I've had Bing hit the three files that are currently visible without searching.

```
[18-Feb-2014 22:51:21 America/Denver] Array
(
    [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /home1/landmat7/public_html
    [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip,deflate
    [HTTP_CONNECTION] => Keep-alive
    [HTTP_HOST] => www.landmarkmissionarybaptistarizona.com
    [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
    [PATH] => /bin:/usr/bin
    [REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
    [REDIRECT_URL] => /recordings/2011-06-05/sermon.Pastor Antonucci.Leftovers II.mp3
    [REDIRECT_dont_vary] => 1
    [REDIRECT_file_gzip] => /ramdisk/cpud/status
    [REDIRECT_no_gzip] => 1
    [REMOTE_ADDR] => 66.249.74.42
    [REMOTE_PORT] => 50666
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
    [REQUEST_URI] => /recordings/2011-06-05/sermon.Pastor%20Antonucci.Leftovers%20II.mp3
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => FILE.php
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => FILE.php
    [SERVER_ADDR] => 69.89.31.250
    [SERVER_NAME] => www.landmarkmissionarybaptistarizona.com
    [SERVER_PORT] => 80
    [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
    [SERVER_SIGNATURE] => <address>Apache Server at www.landmarkmissionarybaptistarizona.com Port 80</address>

    [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache
    [file_gzip] => /ramdisk/cpud/status
    [PHP_SELF] => FILE.php
    [REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1392789081.649
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1392789081
)

[18-Feb-2014 22:51:21 America/Denver] Array
(
    [Accept-Encoding] => gzip,deflate
    [Connection] => Keep-alive
    [Host] => www.landmarkmissionarybaptistarizona.com
    [User-Agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
)
```

Comment: have you tried, manually, to access the rest of the files using the addresses on your sitemap? Be sure that there are no mistakes with that. Can you post a fragment of the sitemap? Any information that you have that can help us to find the problem will help you, so post anything that is relevant.

Comment: @PatomaS the sitemap is [here](http://landmarkmissionarybaptistarizona.com/sitemap.xml). I've also added the SERVER and header data to the main body, with a few non-essential lines removed that looked like they shouldn't be online (Wasn't sure, so figured I'd be safe).

Comment: I recommend that you check section 2 of [Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) to avoid problematic characters, Try to use only letters, numbers and -. Plus your server is not sending the appropriate mime type for those filesm which should be audio/mpeg. Check [how to add a mime type on .htaccess](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how+to+set+mime+types+on+htaccess). After setting the mime type and changing your file names, check again if you can reach them and the results from google

Comment: As in, don't convert my &amp's in the database back to &'s? And I hadn't thought of the fact that Google was getting an octec-stream. I'll change the logic so anything that reports itself as a bot will get an MP3 file, see if that helps any, and report back next time Google hits my site.

Comment: When you submit your sitemap to GWT are any errors reported? (Unencoded `&` is strictly invalid.) Just curious... which search engines support audio / mp3's?

Comment: @w3d There are no errors, and I just checked, I actually am encoding, not decoding &'s. Also not sure, I've seen Google have some logged here and there, so I want them to at least be accessible.

Comment: @PatomaS, I changed how Google get's the MMIE (If you want to test it, add `?html5` to the end of any of the MP3 URLs) and still, the same file is being hit. I would understand if it was the first one, or none, by why the 11th? That's what really gets me.

Comment: Just to be sure, the one that Google is hitting is this one: /2011-05-22/sermon.Bro Rankin.Knowing Him III.mp3. And not other, is that right?

Comment: @PatomaS Sorry, no. #22 (Don't know how I got 11 stuck in my head). sermon.Pastor Antonucci.Leftovers II.mp3

Comment: I can't find any specific problem with them so for now, the only advise I can give you is to rename using only safe characters, like this: sermon-bro-rankin-knowing-him-III.mp3. Be sure that you don't have spaces, dots or any other character like that. Also, be sure that the name of the file, exactly, is the one you use on the sitemap, including caps. It's easier if you name every file with lower case than mixed case.

Comment: @PatomaS, thanks. Everything is in a Db, and it automatically put there when a file is uploaded. I want the case like that in case the file is downloaded. Would it be advantageous to replace all spaces with %20's on the sitemap?

Comment: Doesn't matter how the name is stored, the process that does it can replace characters. And don't mind about the case of the file name. If you have mixed case on the file name, you have to be sure to write properly those names on the links, with the same case.

Comment: Why not serve as `audio/mp3` to everyone, not just to bots?